# What use rm -rf "`pwd`/folder instead of rm -rf ./folder

Tags: shell, rm, pwd

Why would I want to use the command

```sh
rm -rf "`pwd`/folder"
```

instead of

```sh
rm -rf ./folder
```

What reasons are there to prefer one over the other?

Comment: Did someone delete all the comments here, or is the site doing something weird?

Comment: @HackSaw Comments are often deleted by the posters, and sometimes by a moderator if they no longer serve a purpose (remember they are described as "transient information" in the documentation). This is often the case when comments are either better posted as answers, or when they have spun into an idle discussion.

Comment: Thanks, @AdminBee. Never actually seen it happen before. Makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

`` rm -rf "`pwd`/folder" `` is bad and you shouldn't use it. It's only bad due to a corner case, but this corner case could turn out to be a security issue leading to deleting the wrong directory. The corner case is if the current directory ends with a newline character: the command substitution strips trailing newlines, so if the current directory is `/some/where/strange⏎` (where ⏎ stands for a newline), this command would delete `/some/where/strange` instead.

The variant `rm -rf "$PWD/folder"` has no downside over using the `pwd` command, and has the advantage that it doesn't suffer from the corner case of a trailing newline. Every Bourne/POSIX shell updates the `PWD` variable after each directory-changing command (`cd`, `pushd`, etc.) and it has the same value that the `pwd` built-in command outputs. (The external `pwd` command might have a different output, but 1. `pwd` calls the built-in if there is one and all common shells have one, and 2. there is no advantage to using the external command here anyway.)

`rm -rf "$PWD/folder"` has no advantage over `rm -rf ./folder`, however. It has the theoretical downside that `rm -rf "$PWD/folder"` might go over the maximum command line length while `rm -rf ./folder` fits. However the maximum command line length is almost always significantly larger than the maximum file path length, so a command with a single path pretty much always fits.

Using `"$PWD/$foo"` instead of `"$foo"` has the advantage that it's guaranteed not to start with a dash, so it won't [look like an option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells). That's not an issue if the path is spelled out explicitly in the script, only when it's a variable. And `"./$foo"` offers the same protection. Both `"$PWD/$foo"` and `"./$foo"` are correct only when `$foo` is a relative path. So `rm -rf "$PWD/$foo"` has no advantage over `rm -rf "./$foo"`. And as seen above, if there are many paths involved, using the shorter relative form can help to stay under the command line length limit.

Using `"$PWD/folder"` has a clear benefit over `"./folder"` if you're storing it in a variable for later use: it keeps designating the same file even if the script changes to another directory in the meantime. While `rm -rf "./folder"` is perfectly fine, code like this requires an absolute path:

```
output_directory="$PWD/output"
# If interrupted, delete the partial output.
trap 'rm -rf "$output_directory"; exit 1' HUP INT TERM

do_stuff >"$output_directory/file1"
do_more_stuff >"$output_directory/file2"
cd "$output_directory"
further_stuff file1 file2 >file3
```

If `$output_directory` was a relative path, the cleanup code could work before the `cd` command or after, but not both.

Comment: Another corner case arises if the current working directory is moved (e.g. `mv ../this ../new`). But I guess that advantages and disadvantages of `PWD` (which will still be `/path/to/this`) and `.` (which will refer to `new`) would depend on the specific use case.